# Why this winform does not show up after Hide is called on its second iteration?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, code-injection

My current situation is as follow:

- Application A injects my library into Application B
- Application A then uses GetProcessAddress and GetModule to call the OnStart method in my library

Within my OnStart/OnStop method I initiate/hide a winform, in context its something like this:

```
private static PluginManager _pluginManager;
public static void OnStart()
{
    // some log file code here
    if (_pluginManager == null)
    {
        _pluginManager = new PluginManager();
    }
    // some log file code here
    _pluginManager.Show();
    // some log file code here
}

public static void OnStop()
{
    if (_pluginManager != null)
    {
        // some log file code here
        _pluginManager.Hide();
        // some log file code here
    }
}
```

The `PluginManager` winform close event is override to call `Hide()` so technically(I assume) my winform will never be disposed/closed?

- Once application A is done its tasks and will close, it uses GetProcessAddress and GetModule to call the OnStop method of my library

Everything works as expected so far the winform shows up at OnStart and hides on OnStop as expected.

Now when I start Application A again and it calls the OnStart method, the winform never shows up, I don't get any error messages nor anything it simple doesn't open.

I know the function is called because it outputs to the log file the line before and the line after it calls `Show()`.

- As the title says, why the winform doesn't show up in the second iteration?
- What else can I do to find the issue?

On further tests I found out that if I dispose of the winform and reinitialize it, the winform will work for every call:

```
public static void OnStart()
{
    // some log file code here
    if (_pluginManager == null)
    {
        _pluginManager = new PluginManager();
    }
    else
    {
        _pluginManager.Dispose();
        _pluginManager = new PluginManager();
    }
    // some log file code here
    _pluginManager.Show();
    // some log file code here
}
```

However I am still unaware of why this is required given the winform is never disposed of with the initial code.

My case is probably off-topic? As I can't provide you with a reproducible code of the issue and unhappily the above is all I could collect, but hopefully some one will be able to point me in the right direction or where to look at.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you really having this trouble when restarting the main application (A), or are you having this issue when you go to the option in the application that shows your form? I can't see how a full application restart would stop the form from showing up, but I could see possibilities if the application doesn't unload your app domain. Is this a custom-rolled plugin framework or something more well known?

Comment: @RonBeyer application A is a c++ application that can only inject my library into application B and the forms are inside the library, the library is never unloaded until application B closes and the library is accessed as I described above by application A. the library is a plugin manager itself for managed code.

Comment: What happens if you call OnStart() a second time without restarting Application A?  Does it work then?

Comment: @MobyDisk unhappily I don't have access to application A the best I can do with it is close and open it again, however so long application B is open the library is only injected once.

Comment: It sounds like the form is closed and not just hidden. Once closed it cannot just be made visible again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a threading problem.  You should only call .Show() from an [STAThread] and you should call .Hide() from the same thread that called .Show().  So do this:

```
private static ISynchronizeInvoke _invoker = null;

public static void OnStart()
{
    _invoker.Invoke((Action)(() => {
        // some log file code here
        if (_pluginManager == null)
        {
            _pluginManager = new PluginManager();
        }
        // some log file code here
        _pluginManager.Show();
        // some log file code here
    }), null);
}

public static void OnStop()
{
    if (_pluginManager != null)
    {
        // some log file code here
        _pluginManager.Invoke((Action)(() => _pluginManager.Hide()));
        // some log file code here
    }
}
```

I don't know how the application's main is structured, but you can fill in _invoker from any open form.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
//    Application.Run(new Form1());  <-- This is the usual startup

    // Instead, do this to grab an object to invoke on
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    _invoker = form1;
    Application.Run(form1);
}
```

You could also create a wholly separate STAThread and call Application.Run(_pluginManager) instead of pluginManager.Show().

Comment: It was indeed a threading issue, creating a whole STA worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that your PluginManager winform close event is override to call Hide(), did you set *e.Cancel = true*?

```
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post @JoelLegaspiEnriquez but that did not change anything, still doesn't reopens.

Comment: I see would it be possible to see the whole code related to your issue?

Comment: Unhappily I don't have access to Application A or B, all I can show you is the library which is very basic http://pastebin.com/C2TwpgJZ and the windows form is a empty newly created winform with the close method override like u posted.

Comment: Unfortunately PluginManager is blackbox to us. What we can try here is create a test program with two buttons to just invoke PluginManager's Hide() and Show(). This might help troubleshoot the problem if calling those methods directly within your test program will work. This is just to test whether the Hide() and Show() of the plugin is working properly. Hope you find the solution.

Comment: Well I found a solution or rather a workaround but still trying to figure out why that happens, I posted in the original question the work around I found while still looking for the actual answer.